# "Ткнул первое, что попалось(,) и влюбился!" Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед *и* в данном предложении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректно: ткнул **во что-либо**.
Неудачно: *влюбился в первое, что попалось*; влюбляются обычно в кого-то.

Пример правки:

**Ткнул в первое, что попалось, — и влюбился в ту, которая там оказалась!**

Запятая обязательна хотя бы потому, что нужно выделить запятыми придаточное предложение "что попалось". Далее, я бы поставил тире, чтобы подчеркнуть неожиданное следствие.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас главное (без подлежащего): *ткнул, влюбился*, соединённые союзом *и*.

А между ними придаточное *что попалось*. Оно обособляется, так что запятая перед *и* необходима.

Answer (score -1):

В этом случае запятая не нужна

Comment: Ответы должны быть аргументированы.